# Angular - How to resolve "the declaration was marked as deprecated" for .subscribe in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular

In the typescript of Angular-13, I got this code:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appSettingsService.getSettings()
      .subscribe(settings => this.settings = settings,
      () => null,
      () => {
         this.defaultSidebarColor = this.settings.defaultSidebarColor;
         this.defaultBrandlogoColor =  this.settings.defaultBrandlogoColor;
      });
  }
```

But an error came up as shown here:

> "the declaration was marked as deprecated" for .subscribe

And I got .subscribe crossed.

How do I get this sorted out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have the full details and examples: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

To summarize: the signature subscribe(next,error,complete) is getting deprecated in favor of passing an object with one or more of the keys 'next', 'error' and 'complete'.

In your example, you'd refactor this way:

```
  .subscribe({
     next:settings => this.settings = settings,
     error:() => null,
     complete:() => {
        this.defaultSidebarColor = this.settings.defaultSidebarColor;
        this.defaultBrandlogoColor =  this.settings.defaultBrandlogoColor;
     }
  });
```